# gulp-concat : from unknown source to the same destination

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I recently started to use gulp to keep my dev project organized and I've run into a little something that I cant figure out. So this is my task :

```
gulp.task('jsassemble', function () { 
   return gulp
   .src('vendor/proj/**/**/src/assets/js/*.js')
   .pipe(concat('all.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
```

As you can see, it'll fetch every js file in vendor/proj/anyFolder/anySubFolder/src/assets/js, put them together, rename the newly created js 'all.js' and then put it in public/js. The problem is that I would like to have gulp to keep the folder hierarchy, for example :

Source = vendor/proj/anyFolder1/anySubFolder1/src/assets/js/*.js
Destination = public/js/anyFolder1/anySubFolder1/src/assets/js/all.js

Source = vendor/proj/anyFolder1/anySubFolder2/src/assets/js/*.js
Destination = public/js/anyFolder1/anySubFolder2/src/assets/js/all.js

Instead of simply having everything on those folder into a 1 and only public/js/all.js

Is there anyway to do it ? I've tried to google it first but I wasn't able to properly formulate my question in a few words and was given not-wanted results :/

Answer (score 0):

You could create the function which keep your folder hierarchy. In this page (http://www.jamescrowley.co.uk/2014/02/17/using-gulp-packaging-files-by-folder/) you find the solution.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var es = require('event-stream');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var scriptsPath = './src/scripts/';

function getFolders(dir){
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file){
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
   var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

   var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
      return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/*.js'))
        .pipe(concat(folder + '.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename(folder + '.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath));
   });

   return es.concat.apply(null, tasks);
});
```

Comment: Sadly this is not working :/ i got a :   Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\dev\journey5.1\vendor\proj\\**\\**\src\assets\js'
because my scriptsPath isnt known ( the /\*\*/*\*/could be any project/subproject, and i cant tell in advance what it willl be )

Comment: Have you try using scriptsPath = './vendor/proj/'; ? (This method is recursive)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @caballerog who puts my on the right path, here's the explained code :

```
//get every folder from a 'pathTo/Something'
function getFolders(dir){
   return fs.readdirSync(dir)
       return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();

}


var projectsRoot = 'vendor/proj/';
var pathToJsFiles = '/src/assets/js/';
var pathToPublic = 'public/js/';

gulp.task('scripts', function() {

var sites = [];
var pathToProjects = [];

// Fetching every folders in vendor/proj
projects = getFolders(projectsRoot);

// Fetching every subfolder in vendor/proj/something
for(index in projects){
  sites.push(getFolders(projectsRoot + '/' + projects[index]));
}

// Pushing every projects/site that exists into an array
for(var i=0;i<projects.length;i++){
  for(var j=0; j<sites.length; j++)
    if(sites[i][j] != null)
      pathToProjects.push(projects[i] + '/' + sites[i][j]);
}

// Fetching every JS on vendor/proj/pathToAProject/pathToJsFiles
// concatenate them together
// and sending them to pathToPublic/pathToAProject/all.js
var tasks = pathToProjects.map(function(pathToAProject) {
   return gulp.src( projectsRoot + pathToAProject + pathToJsFiles + '/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(pathToPublic + pathToAProject));
});

return es.concat.apply(null, tasks);
});
```

TL:DR = get every JS file in pathToPublic/someFolder/someFolder/PathToJS.